# Is there a way to preload destination view controllers to expedite storyboard segue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, segue

I'm working in iOS 7.1~ with several UIViewControllers in Interface Builder storyboard.

One thing I noticed was how much lag and delay there is when my program performs segues from the top UIViewController (let's called A) to the others (B, C, and D), and, given that I would like to support segues between B, C, and D without passing back to A, I wonder if it makes sense to preload all A, B, C, and D, and then reuse them when the user either goes back or between B, C, and D.

The question is how can I do this?  I am already keeping/saving pointers to each UIViewController in the others once it is created, but when prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue*) is called automatically, the destinationViewController always appears to have a new address, different from the one I saved in my pointer.  I would think that using this provided destination view controller is the same as loading a new one from scratch.

Let's say A has pointers to B, C, and D.  Is there some way to declare B, C, and D, allocate them very early, and then keep reusing the B, C, and D as the user is moving between them?  I thought about and tried giving A some delegate methods that B, C, and D would have A call upon rewinding, but I got error messages telling me A was in the middle of presenting and could not perform the segue to C or D.  So it seems safest to go straight from B to C or D without passing through A.  It still leaves the problem though that relying on prepareForSegue from B seems to give me a new destination controller C or D, and not the one I had saved in A (or B).

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Have yo done any profiling before you assume that Apple's code is the culprit for the slowness? You can preload VCs from a Storyboard and manually perform segues but you defeat the object somewhat.

Comment: No I have not done any profiling, but I still think it's cleaner not to create a new viewcontroller every time I need a transition because it will happen quite often. Whether it's Apple's code or not, I still want the best way to navigate from one to the other in a random, circuitous fashion (A-->B-->C-->A-->B-->C-->B-->D--> ...)

Comment: You will have to do that manually. Apple's storyboard code always creates new VCs. You can switch them in prepareForSegue: without error but it's not documented as far as I know. It also doesn't save you time if you're seeing slow instantiation.

Comment: So you're saying that even if I manually just sub in the VC I allocated already, it doesn't save me the viewDidLoad/.../init/creation of everything inside a new VC during segues?

Comment: Take a look at `UIPageViewController`.  You can instantiate all the VCs, and then use the UIPageViewController to display the one you want.

Comment: Thanks, that's a really good suggestion.  I am also looking at UITabBarViewController, although unsure whether I can make a top view UIViewController without it.

Comment: You can also not use segues and just manipulate the `viewControllers` property of your navigation controller directly.

Comment: So far, the UIPageViewController solution seems to be working out ok. Having a bit of trouble passing data between the various pages, and there is also the slight issue that tapping on a page leads to a page flip even when there is stuff on the page that needs to accept the tap, but the transition between pages is quite smooth.

Comment: Can you explain the problem with page flips?

Comment: In the default implementation of UIPageViewController, single-tapping anywhere on the main view seems to result in a page flip, either forward or backwards. Even if the tap happens inside a selectable object, like a UITableViewCell, a UICollectionViewCell, or a UIButton; I would think the responder chain would stop it, but the page flip still happens. It would be ideal if the page flips only on taps that aren't consumed by other objects, or on swipes starting from the edge of the screen (like a real book)

Comment: @Cindeselia did you solve the problem with page flips?

Comment: I have not, actually, but I took an alternate approach by pre-allocing the controllers on a separate thread and doing some extra logic on the responder chain. I'll post back here once I clean up the code.